# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value Laravel 7

Tags: sql, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a relationship between 2 tables `money_trade` and `money_trade_deposits`. My Schema in `money_trade_deposits` table is:

```
 Schema::create('money_trade_deposits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('mt_dep_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('money_trades_id');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->string('payment_method');
        $table->foreign('money_trades_id')->references('id')->on('money_trades')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

MoneyTradeDepositController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'amount' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'payment_method' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

    ]);

    $moneyTradeDeposit = new MoneyTradeDeposit();
    $moneyTradeDeposit->mt_dep_number = uniqid('MTDepNumber-');
    $moneyTradeDeposit->amount = $request->input('amount');
    $moneyTradeDeposit->payment_method = $request->input('payment_method');
    $moneyTradeDeposit->money_trades_id = MoneyTrade::get('id');
    $moneyTradeDeposit->save();

    return redirect()->route('mt.deposit')->withMessage('Added a New Deposit');
}
```

My MoneyTradeDeposit.php model has

```
protected $table = 'money_trade_deposits';

public function moneytrade()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MoneyTrade::class);
}
```

My blade view has a modal which supplies the inputs of `amount` and `payment_method`. Now I'm trying to get the `id` from my `money_trade` table and insert it to my `money_trade_deposits` table as `money_trades_id`. However I'm getting this error. When I dump $request I can get the values but when I dump $moneyTradeDeposit, I get this complete error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[]' for column `fssdb`.`money_trade_deposits`.`money_trades_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `money_trade_deposits` (`mt_dep_number`, `amount`, `payment_method`, `money_trades_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (MTDepNumber-5f9f198f6c2b3, 1000, MoneyTrade, [], 2020-11-01 20:24:47, 2020-11-01 20:24:47))
```

When I `dd($request)` I get

[image]

When I do `dd($moneyTradeDeposit);` I get

[image]

My `MoneyTradeController.php` for reference has a `store` method which is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'bank' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'mt_first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mt_account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_deposit' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_leverage' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    ]);

    $moneyTrade = new MoneyTrade();
    $moneyTrade->mt_number = uniqid('MTNumber-');
    $moneyTrade->bank = $request->input('bank');
    $moneyTrade->email = $request->input('email');
    $moneyTrade->mt_first_name = $request->input('mt_first_name');
    $moneyTrade->mt_last_name = $request->input('mt_last_name');
    $moneyTrade->password = $request->input('password');
    $moneyTrade->mt_account = $request->input('mt_account');
    $moneyTrade->mt_deposit = $request->input('mt_deposit');
    $moneyTrade->mt_leverage = $request->input('mt_leverage');
    $moneyTrade->user_id = auth()->id();
    $moneyTrade->save();

    return redirect()->route('home')->withMessage('MoneyTrade Account Created');
}
```

And a model `MoneyTrade.php`

```
class MoneyTrade extends Model
{
   // protected $guarded = [];

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

And `money_trades` table schema

```
Schema::create('money_trades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('mt_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('bank');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('mt_first_name');
        $table->string('mt_last_name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('mt_account');
        $table->string('mt_deposit');
        $table->string('mt_leverage');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

It seems like the `money_trades_id` is the issue.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like you are getting an empty array returned from `MoneyTrade::get('id')`, can you post that code here. Or dump the results.

Comment: I am getting a new error now which has value but it's like this `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column `fssdb`.`money_trade_deposits`.`money_trades_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `money_trade_deposits` (`mt_dep_number`, `amount`, `payment_method`, `money_trades_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (MTDepNumber-5f9f1f83d1a02, 1000, MoneyTrade, [{"id":1}], 2020-11-01 20:50:11, 2020-11-01 20:50:11))`

Comment: `MoneyTrade::get('id')` appears to be returning an array objects with an `id` property, probably representing all the `money_trade` rows in the DB. I don't think this is the functionality you a re looking for here.

Comment: Oh I see. When I try to dump you're right it returns an array. How can I change this line of code to get only specifically the `id` from the `money_trades` table?

Comment: How do you know which `money_trade` row should be associated with which `money_trade_deposits` row? Are these being created in the same request?

Comment: Yes, on the same request. O'm only after the `id` row from `money_trades` table to put to my `money_trade_deposits` table as `money_trades_id`. O'm not sure how to do this as I don't know how to revise the code `MoneyTrade::get('id')`. I tried using `MoneyTrade::find('id')` but this don't work since it would give a null value.

Comment: Can you post the `MoneyTrade` code?

Comment: I have added the references from `MoneyTrade`. I've tried other ways but I don't really know how to fix it. Thanks a lot

Comment: after creating a new `money_trade` row with `$moneyTrade->save()`, you can call `$moneyTrade->id` to get the id of the newly added `money_trade` row this is the id that `money_trade_deposits.money_trades_id` references.

Comment: This line causes the error `$moneyTradeDeposit->money_trades_id = MoneyTrade::get('id');` give an integer value and try for a checking,  worked or not

Comment: Sadly, it's still not working. On my `Schema` I have `$table->unsignedBigInteger('money_trade_id');` and I still get the same error  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column fssdb.money_trade_deposits.money_trades_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into money_trade_deposits (mt_dep_number, amount, payment_method, money_trades_id, updated_at, created_at) values (MTDepNumber-5f9f1f83d1a02, 1000, MoneyTrade, [{"id":1}], 2020-11-01 20:50:11, 2020-11-01 20:50:11))`

Comment: How can I change this $moneyTradeDeposit->money_trades_id = MoneyTrade::get('id'); as I'm now sure it really causes the error?

Comment: `$moneyTradeDeposit->money_trades_id` only accept an integer value, like `$moneyTradeDeposit->money_trades_id = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with

```
MoneyTrade::get()->id;
```

To see if it returns the "Value" (in this case: 1)?

Hernan.

PD: i see that in the Schema amount is "integer" and in the store method you validate a "string".

Comment: Hi Hernan! I have tried this and changed the amount to `integer` and there's no error throwing now. However it's still not saving to the database for some reason.